# Rouche's theorem in the right half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

I need to determine the number of zeros in the right half plane Re z>0 of the polynomial:
$$
f(z)=z^3-z+1
$$
My attempt to solve the problem:

I'm using Rouché's theorem and consider
$$
g(z)=z^3+1 ~~ and ~~
p(z)= -z
$$
and it can be seen that $|g(z)|>|p(z)|$ on the imaginary axis and for $|z|$ large.

My conclusion is that the function $f(z)$ has $3$ zeros in the right half plane. Is this correct?

(A solution from the book showed that it has $2$ zeros in $Re\, z>0$ but I'm not sure if it's a typo)

Comment: Based on the partial fraction decomposition
$$
\frac{p(z)}{z^3+1}=1+\frac{1}{3(z+1)}-\frac{z+1}{3(z^2-z+1)}
$$
one can improve the factorization $p(z)=(z+1)(z^2-z+1)-z$ to
\begin{align}
p(z)&=(z+1)(z^2-z+1)+\tfrac13(z^2-z+1)-\tfrac13(z+1)^2\\
&=\left(z+\tfrac43\right)\left(z^2-\tfrac43z+\tfrac23\right)+\tfrac19(z+1)
\end{align}
giving the root locations close to $-\frac43$ and $\frac23\pm i\frac{\sqrt2}3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You correctly derived that $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros in the right half-plane.

Only the final conclusion is wrong: $g(z) = z^3+1$ has *two* zeros in the right half-plane (the third zero is $z=-1$).